# How to delete values from two textboxes by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have three textboxes (multiline), if the second textbox data is available in first one those numbers will be deleted.
like

```
t1:123456,12345678,9898998,4545454,
t2:123456,66666666
```

When I press <kbd>filter</kbd> button the third textbox data will be

```
t3:12345678,9898998,4545454,
```

Code:

```
function GetDistinctElements(source, source1, target) {
    var input = source.value.trim().replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
    var input1 = source1.value.trim().replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
    input = input.filter(function (val) {
        return input1.indexOf(val) == -1;
    });
    var distinctArray = input.filter(function (item, pos) {
        return input.indexOf(item) == pos;  
    });
    target.value = distinctArray.join(',');
}
```

But when I enter `;` after the digit, it will take `;` as a number as well.

If I enter comma (`,`) or semicolon (`;`) it should accept those, and filter will be performed.

Comment: what happens to the 66666666  in your third text box?

Comment: it will be deleted bcoz first textbox does not contain 66666666

Comment: So t3 contains the numbers in t1 that aren't also in t2 and with duplicates removed?

Comment: t3 contains the numbers in t1 that are also in t2..those numbers will be deleted and remainig numbers will be displayed in t3

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any need to use *trim* when you are removing all whitespace anyway.

Comment: when i enter like:123;456,456789 it takes like 123;456as one digit how can i rectify it

Comment: Use a regular expression for the spit: `...split(/[,;]/)` which will split on comma and semicolon.

Comment: @RobG:thanks..it works

Answer (score 0):

I would explode it to an array, iterate, and then recreate the string. This avoids problems the managing the commas that you would have with a simple string replace. Here's the code:

```js
var val1 = $("#1").val();
var val2 = $("#2").val();
var array1 = val1.split(",");
var array2 = val2.split(",");
var val3 = "";
var count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (!($.inArray(array1[i], array2) >= 0)){
        if (count > 0)
            val3 = val3 + ",";
        val3 = val3 + array1[i];
        count++;
    }
}
$("#3").val(val3);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/82etmett/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = source.value.trim().replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/;/g,',').split(',');
```

`replace(/;/g,',')` is all you miss.